# Create partition on bigquery table using terraform

Tags: google-bigquery, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

#### Description

I have list of bigquery tables to be created using terraform but I need only the partition for specific tables.

Here is the ex.

```
locals {
    path = "../../../../../../../../db"

    gcp_bq_tables = [
        "my_table1",
        "my_table1_daily",
        "my_table2",
        "my_table2_daily"
    ]
}
```

And, the terraform script to create the tables:

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "gcp_bq_tables" {
    for_each    = toset(local.gcp_bq_tables)
    dataset_id  = google_bigquery_dataset.gcp_bq_db.dataset_id
    table_id    = each.value
    schema      = file("${local.path}/schema/${each.value}.json")
    labels = {
        env = var.env
        app = var.app
    }
}
```

In that I need to create partition on timestamp, type as DAY but the columns are different.
Lets say for my_table1,

1. The partition column would be my_ts_column_table1 for table1
2. The partition column would be my_last_modified_column_table2 for table2

How to write the terraform script in this scenario.

#### My exploration

I find a way to do it in [terraform_documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_table#nested_time_partitioning) but not sure for multiple tables and how can be specified the partition columns for both tables.

Comment: So what is the issue with the current code?

Comment: How to impalement çreate partition for BQ tables using terraform? In my case I need to create partition for only 2 tables with different fields. How to do that ?

Comment: Which fields would that be? I have an idea, but I need to understand a bit better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it might be the best to use `dynamic` [1] with `for_each` meta-argument [2] to achieve what you want. The code would have to be changed to:

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "gcp_bq_tables" {
    for_each    = toset(local.gcp_bq_tables)
    dataset_id  = google_bigquery_dataset.gcp_bq_db.dataset_id
    table_id    = each.value
    schema      = file("${local.path}/schema/${each.value}.json")

    dynamic "time_partitioning" {
      for_each = each.value == "table1" || each.value == "table2" ? [1] : []
      content {
        type  = "DAY"
        field = each.value == "table1" ? "my_ts_column_table1" : "my_last_modified_column_table2"
      }
    }

    labels = {
        env = var.env
        app = var.app
    }
}
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

[2] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each

Answer (score 2):

I hope this solution can help.

You can configure a json file to create dynamically your tables with partitions.

`tables.json` file

```json
{
    "tables": {
        "my_table1": {
            "dataset_id": "my_dataset",
            "table_id": "my_table",
            "schema_path": "folder/myschema.json",
            "partition_type": "DAY",
            "partition_field": "partitionField",
            "clustering": [
                "field",
                "field2"
            ]
        },
        "my_table2": {
            "dataset_id": "my_dataset",
            "table_id": "my_table2",
            "schema_path": "folder/myschema2.json",
            "partition_type": "DAY",
            "partition_field": "partitionField2",
            "clustering": [
                "field",
                "field2"
            ]
        }
}
```

Then retrieve your tables from `Terraform` local file.

`locals.tf` file :

```
locals {
  tables = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/resource/tables.json"))["tables"]
}
```

I put a default partition in `variables.tf` file on `myDefaultDate` field :

```
variable "time_partitioning" {
  description = "Configures time-based partitioning for this table. cf https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/bigquery_table.html#field"
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    type = "DAY"
    field = "myDefaultDate"
  }
}
```

In the `resource.tf` file, I used a `dynamic` bloc :

- if the partition exists in the current table from the `Json` matadata configuration file `tables.json`, I take it.
- Otherwise I take the default partition given by the `variables.tf` file.

resource.tf file :

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "tables" {
  for_each = local.tables
  project = var.project_id
  dataset_id = each.value["dataset_id"]
  table_id = each.value["table_id"]
  clustering = try(each.value["clustering"], [])

  dynamic "time_partitioning" {
    for_each = [
      var.time_partitioning
    ]
    content {
      type = try(each.value["partition_type"], time_partitioning.value["type"])
      field = try(each.value["partition_field"], time_partitioning.value["field"])
      expiration_ms = try(time_partitioning.value["expiration_ms"], null)
      require_partition_filter = try(time_partitioning.value["require_partition_filter"], null)
    }
  }

  schema = file("${path.module}/resource/schema/${each.value["schema_path"]}")
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer to bring a correction on the usage of dynamic bloc in my example.